# Why am I currently banned from making suggested edits?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, edit-history, android-app

I have only made two edits within the past 7 days, neither of which were rejected.

My [edit history](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/50951/ajmansfield?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) shows no recent rejected suggestions. In fact, using [this data query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/45755/my-rejected-edits) with my userID (50951) shows that my most recent rejected edit was in November 2013.

Why am I banned from making suggested edits?

I am using the mobile app for android; when I press the 'preview' or 'submit' buttons for an edit, a red popup comes down from the top saying 'this user is not allowed to suggest edits'.

Comment: [Here is your suggestion history](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/50951/ajmansfield?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

Comment: @Thursday Ok, thanks. I didn't know that page existed. Although it does not provide a way to show only rejected edits.

Comment: Using my mod superpowers tells me that you are not actually banned from making suggested edits. What makes you think you are?

Comment: It not infrequently happens that someone else (perhaps the OP) is editing the Question (or Answer) in the same time window as you are, esp. if the post has flagrant misspellings or lacks proper MathJax/markdown formatting.  In this case someone is bound to get a message to the effect that their edit could not be submitted.

Comment: @mixedmath I am using the mobile app for android; when I press the 'preview' or 'submit' buttons for an edit, a red popup comes down from the top saying 'this user is not allowed to suggest edits'.

Comment: Some edits, including those creating new tags, are not allowed to make from a mobile phone (for anyone).